# If (condition), add 1 to previous value, else, subtract 1

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm tracking Meals and satiety in a `dataframe`. I would like to have `R` add 1 to the previous value in the satiety column when a meal is eaten, and subtract 1 when no meal is eaten (meal=NA).

I'm trying to accomplish this with a `for loop` nested in an `ifelse` statement but it is not working.

My current attempt:

```
ifelse(Meals=="NA",for (i in 1:length(Day$Fullness)){
  print(Day$Fullness[[i]]-1+i)}, for (i in 1:length(Day$Fullness)){
  print(Day$Fullness[[i]]+1+i)}

Error: Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) 
[test & ok] : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

I'm not sure how to create a table on here but I will do my best to make sense.

Time:  9:30 AM  10:00 AM 10:30 AM  ETC
Meals:  NA  NA  Breakfast  NA  NA  Snack  NA  NA  NA  ETC
Satiety:  Range from 0-10.

My current satiety data is just a vector I created, but I would like it to start at 0 and increase by 1 after every meal, while decreasing by 1 after every 30 minute timeframe where there is no meal(where meal= NA).

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: welcome welcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: also, please provide not only sample data, but also a desired output. Surely, your problem can be solved with a vectorised solution, but difficult really to tell what you want from your question

Comment: This is my first time on stack overflow, I'll edit with more detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample data and a potential solution.

```
set.seed(123)
meals <- sample(c(1, 1, 1, NA), 20, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(meals = meals)
head(df)
#   meals
# 1     1
# 2    NA
# 3     1
# 4    NA
# 5    NA
# 6     1

df$meals[is.na(df$meals)] <- -1
df$satiety <- cumsum(df$meals)
head(df)
#   meals satiety
# 1     1       1
# 2    -1       0
# 3     1       1
# 4    -1       0
# 5    -1      -1
# 6     1       0
tail(df)
#    meals satiety
# 15     1       5
# 16    -1       4
# 17     1       5
# 18     1       6
# 19     1       7
# 20    -1       6
```

I would suggest not coding the absence of a meal (or a skipped meal) as `NA` which means "I don't know". If you're using `NA` to mean the meal was skipped, than you do actually know and you should give it something that represents a skipped meal. Here, since your model interprets a skipped meal as having a negative impact on satiety (not a neutral impact), `-1` actually makes quite a lot of sense. If that's how you use it in your model, then code it that way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

1. Unless the data includes the string "NA", you should use the command `is.na(x)` to check if a value or values are NA. It's hard to tell however without sample data.
2. Generally speaking, in R you will want to use vectorised solutions. In many cases, if you're using a `for` loop, it's incorrect.
3. You've stated that "Meals" is in a dataframe. As such, you will need to refer to Meals as a subset of that data frame. For example, if the data frame is `data`, then the expression should be `data$Meals`.

Summarising all of this, I'd probably do something similar to the following:

```
Day$Meals.na <- is.na(Day$Meals)
print(Day$Fullness + (-1)^Day$Meals.na)
```

This uses a nice trick: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are both stored as `1` and `0` respectively under the hood.

Hopefully this helps. If not, we'd really need sample data and expected outputs to be able to be of more use.

Comment: nice idea with the exponential. no need for creation of a new column. Just `Day$Fullness + (-1)^is.na(Day$Meals)` might make your code more concise. however, this might throw an error because of vector lengths. In summary, we need some sample data :)

Comment: Thanks. I figured that since they're new, it would be worth having a column that they could refer to as a midpoint but you're right, in reality I wouldn't bother with a new column.